# SwiftUI custom TabBar Icons

Tags: swift, tabbar

this is about SwiftUI.

my custom PNG 75x75, Black, Background Transparent TabBar icons doesn't get the color. My Icons are always black, no matter if there active or not. What I'm doing wrong?

```
Text("Test")
   .tabItem {
       Image("MyIcon")
       Text("MyName")
   }.tag(0)
```

Comment: The documentation of UITabBar from UIKit says that you have to provide an image for the selected and unselected state: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritem. I didn't find anything for swiftui though.

Answer (score 10):

The template mode should work here, like

```
Image("MyIcon")
    .renderingMode(.template)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.renderingMode(.template) accomplishes this.
```

If you don't want to add the rendering mode to each image, you can simply select them all in your ***Assets.xcassets*** and change the rendering mode in the right panel under "Render as"

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by @Will Danner, the right way is the one shown in the attached screen shot below. You must change to `Template Image` in `Render As`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I could do this

```
• keep separate images for the selected and unselected version 
• use @State var to define the image names and update it using onAppear and onDisappear
```

Example below

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = 0
    @State var tab0_image = "<custom-image-tab0_unselected"
    @State var tab1_image = "<custom-image-tab1_unselected"

    var body: some View {

        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {

            View_tab0().tabItem({
                Image(tab0_image)
            }).tag(0)
                .onAppear{self.tab0_image = "<custom-image-tab0_selected>"}
                .onDisappear{self.tab0_image = "<custom-image-tab0_selected>"}

            View_tab1().tabItem({
                Image(tab1_image)
            }).tag(1)
                .onAppear{self.tab1_image = "<custom-image-tab1_selected>"}
                .onDisappear{self.tab1_image = "<custom-image-tab1_selected>"}
        }
    }
}
```