# I don't know to set a default TabBar

Tags: swiftui, tabbar

I want to set an image as the background of this TabBar
I tried by many way but it can't
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code for each tab?

Comment: Each Tab is a View, but in that Image, I use Text("") only

Comment: Use something like a label instead. For example `Label("Something", systemName: "house.fill.")`

Comment: I want to change the background of TabBar by an Image, not the TabBar Icon

Comment: I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215407/swiftui-custom-tabbar-icons

Comment: this post will give you the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70928399/i-want-to-set-a-background-to-the-tabbar

Answer (score 1):

I have found the default SwiftUI `TabBar` to be tricky to work with, but luckily it's not too hard to make a custom `TabBar`. This lets you add images or any other `View` as the "tabs."

Example Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedTab: TabPicker.MenuTab = .first
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
        
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
            HStack {
                TabPicker(selectedTab: $selectedTab)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct TabPicker: View {
    enum MenuTab {
        case first
        case second
        case third
    }

    @Binding var selectedTab: MenuTab
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
        
   
            Spacer() // spacers ensure equal spacing between elements
            Text("1") // change these to be whatever views you need
                .fontWeight( selectedTab == .first ? .bold: .light) // some way of indicating which tab is selected
                .onTapGesture { selectedTab = .first }
            Spacer()
            Text("2")
                .fontWeight( selectedTab == .second ? .bold: .light)
                .onTapGesture { selectedTab = .second }
            Spacer()
            Text("3")
                .fontWeight( selectedTab == .third ? .bold: .light)
                .onTapGesture { selectedTab = .third }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set it as a @State var
like so:

```
@State var selectedTab: Int = 0
```

then:

```
TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            YourView()
                .tabItem{
                    VStack {
                        Text("First")
                    }
                }.tag(0)
```

then create YourView