# I want to set a background to the TabBar

Tags: swiftui, tabbar, tabview

I don't know how to change the background of the TabBar by an Image (I try to change the background of TabBar, not try to change the TabBar Icon by an Image)
I tried to set an background to my TabBar such as the TabBar of the program on the right
[image: I tried to set an background to my TabBar such as the TabBar of the program on the right]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have right image in your assets catalog (or prepared in advance), you can set it in view's init, like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "image")
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }

   // ... other code
}
```